# Can't populate ddl on js

Tags: javascript, html

I can't populate a drop down table using javaScript. It doesn't show any element.

I cannot find anything wrong. If someone could help me out, please.

```
<body> 
<h1>lalal</h1>
<form>
    <select id="wineType"></select>
</form>

<script>
    // Populate ddl
    var wineType = document.querySelector('#wineType');
    var types = ['White', 'Red'];

    types.forEach(element => {
        option.textContent = element;
        option.value = element;
        wineType.appendChild(option);
    });
</script>
```

Comment: What's the current behavior ? What's not working ? Do you have anything in developper console ? Your question is not clear enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create `option` element before you can add other attributes on it.

```
 var option = document.createElement("option");
```

```js
var wineType = document.querySelector('#wineType');
    var types = ['White', 'Red'];
   
    types.forEach(element => {
     var option = document.createElement("option");
        option.textContent = element;
        option.value = element;
        wineType.appendChild(option);
    });
```

```html
<h1>lalal</h1>
<form>
    <select id="wineType"></select>
</form>
```

And for every beginner, you should always check your console before getting mad with the problems.